# Firebase Query - Accessing nested object in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase object that looks like this

```
posts: {
  -Kc6CT_CF--kVYApIhD9: {
    -comments: {
       -Kc6CkgQ8-5OztuqHqdS {
         text: "Text here",
         timestamp: 1486179732382,
         user: {
              "username": "user1",
              "email": "some@email.com"
         }
       }
    },
    "lat": "37.8136",
    "lng": "144.9631"
  }
}
```

And I have a POJO that looks like this:

```
public class Post {

    private Comment comments;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String text;
    private String timestamp;
    private Motorist user;


    public Post() {  }

    public Comment getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Comment comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Motorist getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Motorist user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public static class Comment {

        String text;
        String timestamp;
        Motorist user;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public Motorist getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(Motorist user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code where I loop in my `posts` object:

```
Map<String, Post> td = new HashMap<String, Post>();
    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        Post post = postSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

        //for (DataSnapshot commentSnapshot : postSnapshot.child("comments").getChildren()) {
        //    System.out.println(commentSnapshot.getValue());
        //}

        td.put(postSnapshot.getKey(), post);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, postSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I am using the `addValueEventListener`. Now, my problem is I cant get the data in `comments` object. When I run the debugger my `comments` object is `null`. What am I missing? Or is there something wrong with my POJO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code and data structure:

```
-comments: {
   -Kc6CkgQ8-5OztuqHqdS {
     text: "Text here",
     timestamp: 1486179732382,
     user: {
          "username": "user1",
          "email": "some@email.com"
     }
   }
```

If that `-` is indeed in front of `comments`, please remove it. The node should just be called `comments` and adding a `-` prefix just makes it more difficult to handle correctly.

Next up is a problem in your code: under (now) `comments` you have a list of comments, keyed by a push ID (the keys starting with `-K`. In your code you've only modeled a single comment:

```
public class Post {
    private Comment comments;
```

There is no way that the Firebase Database client can map all child nodes of `comments` into that single `Comment`, so it skips it when it reads the JSON. The correct mapping of your JSON structure is:

```
public class Post {
    public Map<String,Comment> comments;
```

If you then only want to handle the values of the comments, you can get them with `post.comments.values()`.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen. The `-` in comment is not necessary, I just copied that from the firebase. I will try to follow your suggestion regarding on my comment. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen. I have a question. Why is it when I query the `comments` data from firebase it only returns the last record. When I try the logger, it displays all the `comments` record.

Here's my [POJO](http://www.writeurl.com/text/e06xkqe21h9kp6vxut34/3yr4yi8filndtrnpkuys/eqc01dyr1lwgap10sef5) : 

Here's my [looping](http://www.writeurl.com/text/fjo7xbuwlx5gcnplmnft/o2p7c1mevuh8ddfc5ewx/xt5vbru3e7e8mlgxz5rh) to get the `posts` and as well as the `comments`...

whats wrong with my structure? I am still learning the technology as of now.